# Enable a flag automatically for specific users using Rules

Tags: rules, users

1. I have a content type called testimonials, and in that I have a user reference field with multiple selection option.
2. I have a flag called 'Request to review' enabled on nodes of 'testimonials' content type.
3. I wrote a rule for sending mail to the author of the node if any user clicked on that flag.

What I need to do here is, I want to enable that flag automatically when a new node is saved only for the users who are selected in the form field user reference. And for remaining users the flag should not be enabled automatically i.e., they have to enable it manually by clicking the flag link.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I achieved it by writing a new rule, in that i wrote a loop for getting all the selected users.

thanks